# How do I launch an application after install in a Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, installation

I have created a setup project using Visual Studio 2008. After the application is finished installing, I would like to have it start up immediately.  Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have used a custom action in [VS 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx). Not sure if this is enhanced in VS 2008.

Answer (score 26):

I've used a script to place a checkbox "Launch [ProductName]" on the final form of the MSI. I cannot take any credit for the script though. You can find the script over on Aaron Stebner's blog   at MSDN http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx

There's an interesting article about it on CodeProject and some good answers there also (which is where I found Aaron's article). 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx

Finally, there's also some other similar questions on StackOverflow

[How to run executable at end of Setup Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565/how-to-run-executable-at-end-of-setup-project)

[How to automatically start my application when my setup is done in C# setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270155/how-to-automatically-start-my-application-when-my-setup-is-done-in-c-setup-proje)

Comment: +1 for Aaron Stebner's script. it worked in my VS2010 setup project.

Comment: Aaron Stebner's script worked for VS2017 setup project

Comment: Does anyone have this script and willing to re-post?  It looks like the link is broken currently?

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to make your application launch after install (using VS2010):

Assuming you already have 2 projects like: `MyApp.Application` and `MyApp.Installer`.

1. Right-click the project for `MyApp.Application` and choose `Add` > `New Item...` > `Installer Class` (name it whatever you want)
2. Right-click the new Installer class & choose `View Code`
3. Override the `Commit` method like this:

   ```
   public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
   {
       base.Commit(savedState);

       Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
       Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\MyApp.exe");
   }
   ```
4. Update `MyApp.exe` to use the name of your application
5. Right-click your `MyApp.Installer` project & choose `View` > `Custom Actions`
6. Right-click the `Commit` folder & choose `Add custom action`
7. Choose `Application Folder` > `OK` > `OK`

#### References:

- [Launching Your Application After Install using Visual Studio 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis)
- [MSDN: Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This causes my installer to hang on installing, is there any fix to this?