# Launch exe after setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I have added some project outputs (which produces some exes) to my Setup project.
 After the setup project finishes doing all the things, the last thing that I want to do this is to run one of these exes from the from the project output.

How can this be done? This is not exactly similar to, but is fairly similar to `Launch after install` thing in setups.

Comment: Can't you just add some code on the OnFinished event (or whatever its called) that simply does a Process.Start(...commandline here....)

Comment: Here is a thread with a similar subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247446/how-do-i-launch-an-application-after-install-in-a-visual-studio-setup-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this through the post build event of the install project. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/12/696833.aspx) should be a good start for you