# run command line command from .net installation setup

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, installation, setup.exe

i have created a installation setup in C#.net using Setup Wizard. I want to run a cmd command or batch file as soon as the setup finishes its work. Is it possible and how?

Comment: I think you could do this via `Process` and `ShellExec`.

Comment: where to add this command...setup is build using setup wizard...

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution for my question...would like to mention if anybody else searching for it:

[How do I launch an application after install in a Visual Studio Setup Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247446/how-do-i-launch-an-application-after-install-in-a-visual-studio-setup-project)

Add required commands to the Installer class in the main application.

Thanks all

Comment: Accept your answer. :)