# How to automatically start my application when my setup is done in C# setup project

Tags: c#, installation

I want that my application start after my setup is finished. I try to launch a cmd file in the custom actions but the VS setup project doesn't want to take the cmd file, this is an invalid custom action file.

I know that I can write an installer class, but is there an easy way to do this simple action?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to run executable at end of Setup Project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565/how-to-run-executable-at-end-of-setup-project) and [How do I launch an application after install in a Visual Studio Setup Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247446/how-do-i-launch-an-application-after-install-in-a-visual-studio-setup-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the following topic it's very useful:
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/Installation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be OK to suggest using innosetup or nsis instead?